# Can Mongrel2 be set to generate a new instance UUID every time it's started?

Tags: zeromq, mongrel2

As per Rule 2 in the Mongrel2 manual(section 5.3.2), every message to and from Mongrel2 has the instance's UUID as the very first thing. And Rule 3(Section 5.3.3) says it's followed by one number after it, which is the connection id, for messages from Mongrel2. Every time I start up Mongrel2, the connection id starts at 0, and increments thereafter. So I am concerned that after a restart of Mongrel2, the reply to a request from the previous instance might get accepted as the reply to a completely different request from the present instance of Mongrel2. Hence my question, if Mongrel2 can dynamically create a new UUID each time it's started. Or if there is a good workaround, other than having to save state, ie check for repeated UUID, connection ids.

Thanks